# Query relationship inside the relationship in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-relations

I am trying to get the news of a writer according to date passed. I have written function so far:

```
public static function getNewsByAuthorByDate($id, $year, $limit = 1){
    return User::where('id', $id)->has('news')
      ->with(['news' => function($q) use(&$limit, &$year) {
         $q->where('created_at', 'like', '%' . $year . '%')->latest()->limit($limit);
      }])
      ->first();
}
```

But the `news[]` is null. Is it possible to get writer news according to date or do I have to try another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [whereYear](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses)

```
public static function getNewsByAuthorByDate($id, $year, $limit = 1){
    return User::where('id', $id)->has('news')
      ->with(['news' => function($q) use(&$limit, &$year) {
         $q->whereYear('created_at',$year)->latest()->limit($limit);
      }])
      ->first();
}
```

and to use limit with eager loading you should use the package [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit)

Comment: Thanks but it returns the same.

Comment: @Gaurav did you use the package recommended as well? Because the above syntax should be working.

Comment: @KurtFriars Just to check I tried removing `limit` the `news[]` is still null.

Comment: @Gaurav Can you try just loading the relation without any contraints? Does that work? If not I am assuming there is an issue with the way you have defined your relation.

Comment: @KurtFriars I removed whereYear and I am getting data inside `news`. But let's say I want to write where clause in `title` column. Is it possible?

Comment: @Gaurav Forget constraining it for a moment. Does User::where('id', $id)->with(['news'])->first(); return news for a user where you would expect it to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217731/discussion-between-gaurav-and-kurt-friars).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

> The `limit` and `take` query builder methods may not be used when constraining eager loads.

Also, You don't need to use `has` method, the `news` would be empty if the user has no news:

```php
return User::with(['news' => function($q) use($year) {
         $q->whereYear('created_at', $year)->latest();
      }])
      ->find($id);
```